# Django restrict options of ManyToMany field in ModelForm based on model instance

Tags: django, django-forms, manytomanyfield

I want to show only options already stored in models' `ManyToManyField`. 
I have model `Order` which I want to have a Model based form like this:

```
class OrderForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['amount', 'color']
```

Now I do not want to display all colors as choices, but instead only color instances saved in `ManyToManyField` of another model. The other model is Design:

```
class Design(models.Model):
    color = models.ManyToManyField('maker.Color')
    # ...
```

Is this at all possible while using `ModelForm`?

### Attempt

I have tried doing it by having a ModelForm of Design and setting instance:

```
class ColorForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Design
        fields = ['color']
```

And then in view:

```
color_form = ColorForm(instance=design)
```

But I don't exactly understand what setting instance does, and I think instance is not what I am looking for as it still lists all colors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `instance` setting has nothing to do with limiting the choices. In essence, it simply populates the form's values with the ones from a specific record. You usually provide an instance in an edit operation, whereas you skip it in an add operation.

The representation of a `models.ManyToManyField` in the  `ModelForm` is a `forms.ChoiceField` for which you can simply override its `queryset` property, and specify the queryset you desire.

Therefore, in your view:

```
form = OrderForm()
form.fields['color'].queryset = Design.object.all()  # for example
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer.